# Always get video format not supported when posting a video

Tags: java, video, facebook-graph-api, upload

I am trying to use the graph API to upload a video to a users wall. The result is always an error response of "{"error":{"message":"(#352) Video file format is not supported","type":"OAuthException"}}". I have tried several different video types that are all supported based on this list, http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/video/. Based on my understanding of the documentation i have found, all that needs to be done is send a multipart form data request to "https://graph-video.facebook.com/me/videos" via a POST. BTW, I have been able to post a photo using similar techniques. The code i am using is below. It is based off of the PHP example at, http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/493/. I have been able to upload the different videos using the facebook upload mechanism, so i know the videos are ok for Facebook. The access token is valid because i have used it to post a photo via the Graph API.

Any suggestions to what i am missing are welcome!

Here is the Java Code that i am using:

```
File video = new File(pathtovideofile);
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(video));
byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)video.length()];           
dis.read(bytes, 0, (int)video.length());

// set up the http client, the http method, and the multipart entity
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://graph-video.facebook.com/me/videos");
MultipartEntity mpEntity  = new MultipartEntity( );

ContentBody cbVideo     = new ByteArrayBody(bytes, "video/mp4", "Video Label");
ContentBody cbMessage     = new StringBody( "New Video" );
ContentBody cbTitle     = new StringBody( "Video Title" );
ContentBody cbAccessToken = new StringBody( accessTokenStr1 );

mpEntity.addPart( "access_token", cbAccessToken );
mpEntity.addPart( "file",         cbVideo        );
mpEntity.addPart( "description",  cbMessage     );
mpEntity.addPart( "title",        cbTitle     );

// put the multipart entity into the request
httppost.setEntity(mpEntity);
// send the request
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

// get the response entity
HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
// read the stream and print out the results
InputStream instream = resEntity.getContent();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(instream));
String line;
StringBuilder responsestr = new StringBuilder();
while (( line = reader.readLine()) != null) {               
  responsestr.append(line);
}
System.out.println(responsestr.toString());
```

Answer (score 2):

In php this worked for me. First upload the file to server and then try API call using Graph API.

```
$fbvideo_upload=move_uploaded_file($_FILES['attach_video']['tmp_name'],$fbvideo_path);
chmod($fbvideo_path,0777);                  
if($fbvideo_upload)
{
    $args = array('message' => $status, "access_token" =>$accesstoken,"file" 
            => '@'.$fbvideo_path, "title"=>$video_title, "description"=>$video_desc);
    $post_url = "https://graph-video.facebook.com/me/videos?access_token=".$accesstoken;
    $ch = curl_init();                  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $post_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $args);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);                     
    $data=json_decode($data,true);                      
    if(file_exists($fbvideo_path))
    {                           
        @unlink($fbvideo_path);                         
    }
}
```